# Azure Bot service talking to Azure Logic App - 401 unauthorized

Tags: azure, logic, bots

I have an Azure bot which is all developed and working fine. It currently talks to a 3rd party workflow application via a simple webhook.

I am now trying to replicate this using Azure Logic App. I have a simple logic app that responds fine to requests from POSTMAN. However, when I set the Messaging Endpoint in the Azure Bot service to the URL of the logic app's top node (when a http request is received), I see 401 unauthorized responses from all of my channels in the bot and I don't know why. POSTMAN is using the exact same target URL and works fine.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Please check header of the request you are sending using Postman.

Comment: The only headers sent by POSTMAN are:   Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9add2746-b985-03be-8c34-64e4b300192a

Comment: The fact I am getting a 401 when the Bot service tries to call the Azure logic workflow implies the workflow expects an authentication. But there is no authentication setup on that workflow.

Comment: OK so making some headway. If I change the top node in the Azure logic flow to a GET rather than the a POST then the bot connects fine but then of course does not run as sending data to the workflow requires a POST. So it seems that the Bot service needs to be able to do a GET and POST against the messaging endpoint? Is that true? If so, how to do that in Azure logic app.

Comment: I am sorry buddy but if you resolve this issue  please post the details.

Comment: `getting a 401, but there is no authentication setup on that workflow` Every request endpoint for a logic app should include a [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app#secure-access-to-trigger) as part of the URL, do you include SAS in your URL? Besides, you said it works if you change the request method to GET. Can you share some screenshots to show how you design your Logic app via **Logic APPs Designer**?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and found the solution was to first ensure an Authorization header is being sent, and 2nd, set the value to null.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements#action-authorization-header